# Scroll event conflict in Android WebView when WebView's parent is a Viewpager

Tags: android, webview, scroll, android-viewpager, conflict

**    As said in the title, when WebView's parent is a Viewpager, the progress bar in the audio or video element has a poor effect. Sometime it's hard to drag or may cause the Viewpager flip over. So, anybody knows how to solve this problem? Please help!!! Thanks a lot!
**

Answer (score 0):

You can disable parent touch for a while when touch on the webview, or you can do as you want according to condition.
below is the sample code. I wrote the code for scrollView, you can use it as you want

```
    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View __v, MotionEvent __event) {
            if (__event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //  Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(__v, true);
            } else if (__event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || __event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                // Re-allows parent events
                requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(__v, false);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


private void requestDisallowParentInterceptTouchEvent(View __v, Boolean __disallowIntercept) {
    while (__v.getParent() != null && __v.getParent() instanceof View) {
        if (__v.getParent() instanceof ScrollView) {
            __v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(__disallowIntercept);
        }
        __v = (View) __v.getParent();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to affect the whole WebView, just audio or video element. But now I can't get the childView in WebView. And i use hierarchyviewer.bat to see the view tree, I found WebView have no childView! Has any way to get the audio or video element view?